# Sync data over WLAN between android and pc?

Tags: android, windows, data-synchronization, wifi

I have the following problem:

I'd like to create an Android app and Windows application which syncs its data between each other seamlessly over local WiFi. So that you can continue your work exactly where you left off if you switch from phone to pc or the other way around.

I wouldn't like to use cloud services as there would be large amounts of data to sync between devices. Data doesn't need to go over internet, WLAN is good enough. I thought about using the Bit-torrent Sync API (as the app works flawlessly for me), but apparently the API doesn't support mobile devices yet.

How would I go about this?

Comment: 1) Your question is way too broad for SO format, and 2) I think you have some misunderstandings about networking ("it only supports desktop connections" makes no sense to me) you need to work up first.

Comment: Well... It does? You can't use the API to sync data between a desktop computer and an Android device. So I need a different solution. How should I have worded that differently?

Comment: Can you detail exactly why not? From a OSI model perspective, there's no difference between Android and a desktop computer. In fact there are Bittorrent clients for Android.

Comment: Their [FAQ](https://www.getsync.com/api/faq) says so...
"Does the API support developing for mobile devices?
Not at this time."

Comment: But that's a cloud service, and you said *"I wouldn't like to use cloud services"*...

Comment: Do you even know what you're talking about? Please leave if you don't. Bittorrent Sync IS NOT a cloud service. It never sends your data to an online server to store. It just moves your data between two devices peer-to-peer. Are you a troll or something?

This doesn't even matter anyway because I can't use it, I need a different solution.

Comment: Well, [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/sync-files-wirelessly-between-your-pc-and-android-with-myphoneexplorer/) has this functionality, so it's possible, but probably way too detailed to answer how here.

Comment: Or [SyncMe Wireless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bv.wifisync&hl=en)